# SQL query looking for previous day that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, date, teradata

This is technically for Teradata, though it's similar in SQL. Alright it's possible that this same error would not occur in a SQL query, if so, maybe someone with Teradata experience can answer this. I have a query that ends with:

```
WHERE DB.LOG_DATE > DATE - INTERVAL '6' MONTH;
```

It worked fine until today, and I am guessing it's not working today because February 30 is not a thing. Not sure if there's an easy solution, but sure hoping, maybe something like

```
WHERE DB.LOG_DATE > ROUND(DATE - INTERVAL '6' MONTH);
```

Or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Teradata logic, it's stupid Standard SQL (In fact you can't use INTERVAL-syntax for both YEAR and MONTH).

That's why there's ADD_MONTHS :-)

```
WHERE DB.LOG_DATE > ADD_MONTHS(DATE,-6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from a TD Forum post. For those stumbling upon this in the future...

ADD_MONTHS(DATE,-6)